# CSS circular menu <a href>

Tags: css, hyperlink, menu

I want to add links to circularmenu found on https://jsfiddle.net/zv5dr670/4/.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <li>
    <input id='1' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='1'>Option 1</label>
  </li>
</a>
```

The link is displayed in browser status bar, but dooesn't react on a click. I don't work CSS in school for now, only HTML. Can you help me?

Comment: in the fiddle the menu1, menu2 .... ve to become a link??

Comment: <label for='c1'><a href="http://www.google.de" target="_blank">Menu 1</a></label> ??? You need a link to click on it :p or I don't unterstand you?! https://jsfiddle.net/zv5dr670/15/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom attribute to `li` element as follows

```
<li class='link' data-url='https://jsfiddle.net'>
  <input id='c1' type='checkbox'/>
  <label for='c1'>Menu 1</label>
</li>
```

Then with jQuery you can bind the `link` class' `click event` like this:

```
$('li.link').click(function(e) {
    window.location=$(this).attr('data-url');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make outer circles just links you don't have to use input tag:

HTML

```
<div class='selector'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
  </ul>
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
<button class ="mycbutton">Click2</button>
```

CSS

```
html,
body { height: 100%; }
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#eeeeee, #cccccc);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mycbutton {

}
.selector {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  margin-left: -70px;
}
.selector,
.selector button {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.selector button {
  float:right;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #428bca;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all .1s;
}
.selector button:hover { background: #3071a9; }
.selector button:focus { outline: none; }
.selector ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -20px;
}
.selector li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.selector li a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 1px;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out, color 0.1s, background 0.1s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.selector li a:hover { background: #f0f0f0; }
.selector.open li a {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

JS

```
var nbOptions = 9;
var angleStart = -360;

// jquery rotate animation
function rotate(li,d) {
    $({d:angleStart}).animate({d:d}, {
        step: function(now) {
            $(li)
               .css({ transform: 'rotate('+now+'deg)' })
               .find('a')
                  .css({ transform: 'rotate('+(-now)+'deg)' });
        }, duration: 0
    });
}

// show / hide the options
function toggleOptions(s) {
    $(s).toggleClass('open');
    var li = $(s).find('li');
    var deg = $(s).hasClass('half') ? 180/(li.length-1) : 360/li.length;
    for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
        var d = $(s).hasClass('half') ? (i*deg)-90 : i*deg;
        $(s).hasClass('open') ? rotate(li[i],d) : rotate(li[i],angleStart);
    }
}

$('.selector button').click(function(e) {
    toggleOptions($(this).parent());
});

$('.mycbutton').click(function(e) {
    toggleOptions($(this).parent());
});

setTimeout(function() { toggleOptions('.selector'); }, 100);
```

Run it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zv5dr670/16/)